# SQL select records with different values in same column

Tags: sql

This is a table containing `product_id`s and their features

```
| product_id | feature_title | feature_value |
+------------+---------------+---------------+
|    6312    |   warranty    |       1       |
|    6312    |     color     |      red      |
|    2083    |   warranty    |       1       |
|    2083    |     color     |     blue      |
|    8686    |   warranty    |       0       |
|    8686    |     color     |      red      |
```

How do I select records with these specifics only:

```
warranty = 1
color = red
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
select *
from (
    select product_id
        ,max(case when feature_title = 'warranty' then feature_value end) warranty
        ,max(case when feature_title = 'color' then feature_value end) color
    from yourTable
    group by product_id           -- grouping to one row per id
   ) pivot
where
    warranty = '1' and
    color = 'red';
```

[**My SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63f30/4)
[**SQL Server Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ac2e7/1)

When I want to compare multiple records with same id, I prefer to grouping those records to one row like pivoting a table, A way for pivoting data is by using `max(case)` as showed above in the inner select.
For example result of `case when feature_title = 'warranty' then feature_value end`  will be `feature_value` when `feature_title` is `'warranty'` and for other `feature_title`s it will be `null` so `max` of nulls and `feature_value` will be `feature_value`. -HTH

Comment: Thanks. It worked but I didn't understand this query
really terrible query

Answer (score 2):

I would just do this using aggregation:

```
select product_id
from t
group by product_id
having sum(case when feature_title = 'warranty' and feature_value = '1' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when feature_title = 'color' and feature_value = 'red' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

First, not all databases support `pivot`.  Second, I don't think the subquery adds much to the query.

Note:  Perhaps a simpler version is:

```
select product_id
from t
where (feature_title = 'warranty' and feature_value = '1') or
      (feature_title = 'color' and feature_value = 'red')
group by product_id
having count(distinct feature_title) = 2;
```